# Using edit message in a telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to edit messages in a telegram bot.
I'm using the following code. I can send messages with no problem, but the edit message part doesn't work. It just doesn't do anything!!

```
   <?php

if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
$url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $url");
exit;
}

$botToken="XXXX...";
$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);
$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];

switch($message) {
    case("action"):
                sendMessage($chatId, "What should I do?");
    break;

    case("add"):
        editMessageText($chatId, "should I add?");

    break;

default:
    sendMessage($chatId, "default");
}

function sendMessage($chatId, $message) {

$url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?    chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message)."&reply_markup".$reply1;
file_get_contents($url);
}

function editMessageText($chatId, $messageId, $message) {

$url = $GLOBALS[website]."/editMessageText?chat_id=".$chatId."&message_id=".$messageId."&text=".urlencode($message);
file_get_contents($url);

}

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}


?>
```

Any idea about what can be wrong with it?
Thanks

Comment: this question is too generic, there is no way to know the cause of the issue.
check if you're using all the variables, what does ``file_get_contents `` return?, check if you're using the full ``$url``.
Also you could check If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

Comment: You should enable `error_reporting(-1)` when developing. `$GLOBALS[website]` should warn you about something.. That, unless you go against all standards when defining constants lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in this part of your code

```
case("add"):
    editMessageText($chatId, "should I add?");
```

You are not passing the parameters correctly. [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#editmessagetext) method requires a parameter `message_id`, which should be an `Integer.

This should be the working code

```
    <?php

    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
    $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
    }

    $botToken="XXXX...";
    $website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

    $content = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $update = json_decode($content, true);
    $chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
    $message = $update["message"]["text"];
    // get message_id
    $messageId = $update["message"]["message_id"];
    switch($message) {
        case("action"):
                    sendMessage($chatId, "What should I do?");
        break;

        case("add"):
        // add the 2nd parameter
            editMessageText($chatId, $messageId, "should I add?");

        break;

    default:
        sendMessage($chatId, "default");
    }

    function sendMessage($chatId, $message) {

    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?    chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($message)."&reply_markup".$reply1;
    file_get_contents($url);
    }

    function editMessageText($chatId, $messageId, $message) {

    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/editMessageText?chat_id=".$chatId."&message_id=".$messageId."&text=".urlencode($message);
    file_get_contents($url);

    }

    function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [official Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) say:

> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.

You may be able to use the [`editMessageReplyMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) API.

Comment: This is not a relevant information anymore. You can edit messages with reply_markup.

Comment: Please send me the link of this subject on the Telegram site, so that I can add it to the answer information as an update. @DzhakharUkhaev

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this question is quite old and this is my first answer, If someone is having the issue with `editMessageText`

You need to understand few points very clearly :

1 - ONLY MESSAGES SENT BY A BOT Could be edited by bot. Bot can't edit messages sent by a human.

2- editMessageText requires 3 parameters :

`editMessageText($chatId, $messageId, "MY TEXT THAT WILL REPLACE");`

- mentioned by ManzoorWani already.

3 - The code by ManzoorWani would not work because the `$messageId` is still giving human message id, so you would be getting an 400 permission error.

You would need to put :
`$messageId = $messageId -1`
to get the id of text sent by bot earlier,
First try the `action` message then try to edit message, bot shall reply you something by `action` message and by `add` you would be replacing bot text.

EXAMPLE from the code above:

```
function editMessageText($chatId, $messageId, $message) {
$messageId=$messageId-1;
$url="https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOTAPI]/editMessageText?chat_id=".$chatId."&message_id=".$messageId."&text=".$message;
file_get_contents($url);       
 }
```

4 - `$messageId` always reflects a sequence,  like 1,2,3,4 so the id of the next message is obvious , you can perform actions accordingly.

ANOTHER tip is to first try browser to edit the text sent by bot using url if you are doing this for the first time just to be sure its working.